# Render buttons in lightning data table in salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I am having  issues with rendering standard buttons on each row of a lighting data table in lwc. If I have just single record the action buttons are not displaying properly.

Any sample code will be highly appreciated.[[image: Standard buttons viewon click of dorpdown]

Comment: Hey Sai, Please share your code so that we can help you.

Comment: What do you mean my `not displaying properly`? Please explain.